# Check how many users launch my apple application on their devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have published an application on the apple store, and hope to know how many users launch my application on their devices.

But how can I know it? Do we need to implement some sort of code in my application? If yes, I will implement it for the next version, because my first version is already on the apple store?
I need your help, thank you!

Comment: Same question Again ? [Your Old Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759856/customer-reviews-and-app-analytics-on-the-apple-store)

Comment: Yes you need to add some code to your app to tell a central server when they start it up.  Remember they may not have a network connection though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Analytics for counting the active users using below code

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:GOOGLE_TRACKING_ID];
```

If you want to check the unique users then you can use flurry or you can do this by web service.